# How to create a Pure-Python wheel

Tags: python, setup.py, python-wheel

From the following setup.py file, I am trying to create a pure-python wheel from a project that should contain only python 2.7 code.

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='foo',
    version='0.0.1',
    description='',
    url='',
    install_requires=[
        'bpython',
        'Django==1.8.2',
    ],
)
```

However, when I run `python setup.py bdist_wheel` the wheel file that is generated is platform specific `foo-0.0.1-cp27-none-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl` wheel file instead of the expected `foo-0.0.1-cp27-none-any.whl`.  When I try to install this wheel on a different platform it fails saying `it is not compatible with this Python`.

I there something I need to change about the setup.py file or python interpreter, perhaps, that will allow this wheel to be used on any platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the classifiers field to my setup.py fixed this issue.

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='foo',
    version='0.0.1',
    description='',
    url='',
    classifiers=[
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
    ],
    install_requires=[
        'bpython',
        'Django==1.8.2',
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 11):

The simplistic way is to add `--universal` to your commandline, as you can see from running `python setup.py bdist_wheel --help`:

```
  --universal       make a universal wheel (default: false)
```

Alternatively you can add a `setup.cfg` file next to your `setup.py` that
takes care of this:

```
[bdist_wheel]
universal = 1
```

If you don't like yet another configuration file clobbering your package, 
you can just write such a file in your `setup.py` just before it calls `setup()` and then remove it after that call returns, this is what I do 
in the shared [`setup.py`](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/src/cb145ae09f937e7eac9a1855e7b61932881347f5/setup.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) for all my projects on PyPI e.g. used in [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml).

Comment: The question is not asking how to make a universal wheel.

Answer (score 4):

This part of the filename is controlled by the `bdist_wheel` option called [python tag](https://github.com/pypa/wheel/commit/b101589978458740ab5c6001078acc5e77c41ccc):

```
python2 setup.py bdist_wheel --help | grep python-tag
  --python-tag      Python implementation compatibility tag (default: 'py2')
```

However the default is generally `'py2'` (or `'py3'` for a python3 runtime),  so to get a platform-specific wheel you must have something else in your configuration that is not shown in the question.

Regardless, you can specify the tag explicitly in your setup file:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="foo",
    version="0.0.1",
    ...
    options={"bdist_wheel": {"python_tag": "cp27"}},
)
```

This configuration will create a wheel named `foo-0.0.1-cp27-none-any.whl`.