# Python Wheels on linux (how? and why?)

Tags: python, pypi, python-wheel

I know that wheels are binary version of a module uploaded on PyPI.

with `pip install`

- On Windows: I get wheels downloaded and installed.
- On Ubuntu: I should get the source distribution of the package **BUT** in [some cases](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyQt5/5.6) I get wheels.
- On fedora: *Tricky* I have to install with dnf

I tried to add **wheels** to [my package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ModernGL) as well. But I am only able to upload wheels for windows.

- Why do some packages provide wheels for Linux platform?
- Is this okay? Providing binaries instead of the source?
- Why I cannot provide wheels?

Note: I know a bit about Fedora rpm packages. I am interested now in wheels on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why do some packages provide wheels for Linux platform?

Why shouldn't they, as long as source distributions are available as well? :)

Your question is not clear. If you meant

> Why do some packages provide platform-specific wheels for Linux platform instead of platfom-independent ones?

then take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31573107/how-to-create-a-pure-python-wheel) and its answers. If not, please clarify your question.

---

> On Ubuntu: I should get the source distribution of the package BUT in [some cases](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyQt5/5.6) I get wheels.

Try using:

```
pip install --no-binary :all: somepackage
```

This should make `pip` download a source distribution if it exists on PyPI. I don't know why there are no source packages for PyQt5 on PyPI, probably because they are not installable with `pip` and need a whole toolchaing for compilation.

---

> Is this okay? Providing binaries instead of the source?

It's okay as long as you provide both binaries and the source. I suggest you doing so.

---

> Why I cannot provide wheels?

Try `python setup.py bdist_wheel`. You need to install `wheel` package (on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel)) to make it work. If your package supports both Python 2 and 3 and contains no C extensions, append the `--universal` option to make a "[universal wheel](https://packaging.python.org/distributing/#universal-wheels)".

Replace `bdist_wheel` with `sdist` to make a source distribution. It will create an archive in `dist` directory.

> **sdist** creates the archive of the default format for the current platform. The default format is a gzip’ed tar file (`.tar.gz`) on Unix, and ZIP file on Windows.
>
> You can specify as many formats as you like using the `--formats` option, for example:
>
> ```
> python setup.py sdist --formats=gztar,zip
> ```
>
> to create a gzipped tarball and a zip file

(Quote from https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/sourcedist.html)

---

More info about packaging and wheels is available here: https://packaging.python.org/distributing/#packaging-your-project

Comment: When I try to upload wheels on Linux I get an error, I will paste it here as soon as I can. (today)

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/current/#id8 "PyPI currently only allows uploading Windows and Mac OS X wheels, and they should be compatible with the binary installers provided for download from python.org. Enhancements will have to be made to the wheel compatibility tagging scheme before linux wheels will be allowed."