# Build a universal wheel from setup.py

Tags: python, python-wheel

How do I build a universal wheel from `setup.py`? I would prefer not to pass in the `--universal` option each time or to create a `setup.cfg` file just for this option.

I am aware of the workaround in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35112241/6947337, but is there a clean way of doing this without creating a `setup.cfg` file temporarily?

Comment: Any good reason you needed to avoid using a `setup.cfg`, or just perfectionism?

Comment: There is no reason that I can't use a `setup.cfg` in this case, so this is just perfectionism and curiosity :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

setup.py's `setup()` supports an `options` argument to pass options to any command. It is a dictionary of command names and command options. You can instruct it to build a universal wheel by providing any truthy value accepted by [strtobool](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/distutils/util.py#L294) e.g.

```py
setup(options={'bdist_wheel':{'universal':'1'}})
```

or

```py
setup(options={'bdist_wheel':{'universal':True}})
```

See also https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/distutils/dist.py#L247

If you only want to make a Python 3 compatible wheel, you don't have to pass any argument. The wheel will automatically be tagged as py3 if it it is built in a Python 3 interpreter.

Comment: What are the the options, I only want to make a python3 compatible wheel.

Comment: You don't need to pass any options to make a python3 compatible wheel. The wheel will be automatically tagged with the current python3 interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `script_args` option to `setup()` to override the command line. So you could do:

```
import sys
from setuptools import setup
setup(script_args=sys.argv[1:]+['--universal'])
```

This is not superbly elegant, but perhaps less ugly than creating a temporary setup.cfg