# How do I add a Python tag to the bdist_wheel command using setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools, continuous-deployment, python-wheel

Let's say I have a simple library which uses [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for packaging and distributing. The library in this case also requires a minimum version of Python 3.6, meaning my setup.py would be something like as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='something',
    version='0.0.1',

    description='description',
    long_description=long_description,

    # More metadata

    packages=find_packages(exclude=['tests', 'docs']),

    python_requires='>=3.6'
)
```

Now, when I run `python setup.py bdist_wheel`, I get a file named `something-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl`. As evident here, wheel is ignoring the `python_requires` option in `setuptools` when determining the Python tag for my wheel (it should be `py36` but is the default `py3`). Obviously, I realize that I can just pass in `--python-tag py36` from the command line, which will do the job, but the continuous deployment service I am using for deploying my library only takes in the name of the distribution I am using (`bdist_wheel`). As such, I cannot pass any command line parameters.

After doing a bit of research, I found that I could inherit from the `bdist_wheel` class and override the `python_tag` member variable, but according to the wheel README:

> It should be noted that wheel is **not** intended to be used as a library, and as such there is no stable, public API.

Because of this, I want to avoid inheriting from the `bdist_wheel` class which might force me to rewrite my class every time some breaking change occurs.

Is there any alternative way through setuptools which allows me to pass in the Python tag for a wheel?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Every command line argument for every `distutils` command can be persisted in setup config file. Create a file named `setup.cfg` in the same directory your `setup.py` resides in and store the custom `bdist_wheel` configuration in there:

```
# setup.cfg
[bdist_wheel]
python-tag=py36
```

Now running `python setup.py bdist_wheel` will be essentially the same as running `python setup.py bdist_wheel --python-tag py36`.

Relevant article in the `distutils` docs: [Writing the Setup Configuration File](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/configfile.html).

Comment: Glad I could help! as for the docs, I guess this should fit: [Writing the Setup Configuration File](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/configfile.html) from the `distutils` docs.

Comment: It is also possible to specify this directly in `setup.py`, to avoid a `setup.cfg` file cluttering up the project directory.  See [How to create a Pure-Python wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69994447/674039) for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could hack in something like

```
if 'bdist_wheel' in sys.argv:
    if not any(arg.startswith('--python-tag') for arg in sys.argv):
        sys.argv.extend(['--python-tag', 'py36'])
```

but it's arguably just as brittle...

Comment: I don't think this is brittle in the terms of compatibility (since the cli argument _is_ the public api). However, would this solution work if the code ran something like `python setup.py bdist_wheel sdist`?