# Specify Python tag for wheel using Poetry

Tags: python, python-wheel, python-poetry

I'm thinking of migrating my Python library from [Pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/) with `setup.py` to just [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/). Previously, in order to build my project, I would run

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

For the package I'm building, the minimum supported Python version is 3.6, so I've added the following in a `setup.cfg` file so that this is specified in the built wheel (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52609945/6525260)):

```
[bdist_wheel]
python-tag = py36
```

However, with Poetry, the `poetry build` comamnd is used, which ignores this section in `setup.cfg` and instead puts a general `py3` tag on the wheel. Is there any equivalent way to get the tag onto the generated wheel using Poetry?

Answer (score 1):

The only config file that poetry considers is `pyproject.toml`. It is documented [here](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/), which should help you port all relevant info over. The particular tag that you're asking for would be the python version:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "example"
version = "0.1.0"
...

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.6"  # having something here is mandatory for a build to work
```

A wheels-build will then contain the following in `example.whl/example-0.1.0.dist-info/METADATA`:

```
...

Requires-Python: >=3.6,<4.0
...
```

Comment: I do have the line you mentioned in `pyproject.toml` but I'm looking for a way to modify the tag on the wheel itself, i.e instead of `package-py3-none-any.whl` I want a generated `package-py36-none-any.whl` if its possible through poetry.

Comment: The `bdist_wheel` option with `setup.py` has the `--python-tag` option. I was looking for the equivalent for Poetry. I could modify it by hand, but do not want to unless necessary.

Comment: strictly speaking, the wheel name is arbitrary and you can rename it by hand (or script) to whatever you want - any packaging tool will only look at the metadata, which is already set up correctly.

Comment: So it looks like I'll have to add it by hand. That's unfortunate. I'll consider opening an issue on the poetry repository to perhaps add a config option for this case.